# How to configure database specific settings with PgBouncer?

Tags: pgbouncer

We have a server running multiple services and we would want to use pretty short `client_idle_timeout` for one backend database and unlimited `client_idle_timeout` for another backend database. However, it appears from the documentation that the timeouts must be defined in section `[pgbouncer]` so it appears those are global settings.

For example, when I have database specific connection strings defined in section `[databases]` such as

```
test-short-timeout = host=... port=... ...
test-unlimited-timeout = host=... port=... ...
```

How can I specify that database `test-short-timeout` should have `client_idle_timeout` set to `60` and the database `test-unlimited-timeout` should have it set to `0` (which means unlimited)?

I'm running PgBouncer version 1.12 and it seems that at least following config line in section `[databases]` causes the whole line to be silently(!) ignored:

```
test-unlimited-timeout = host=... port=... ... client_idle_timeout=0
```

so you cannot apply database specific settings that way.

Comment: why do you want to use client_idle_timeout? per docs `This should be larger than the client-side connection lifetime settings, and only used for network problems` (to detect network problems it is better to enable tcp keepalive)

Comment: I want to force client to be disconnected if it hangs in idle state for whatever reason. The expected use case for this client class is to connect, do stuff rapidly and then disconnect and I want to enforce it in case client software has a bug in in future. I know that this class can detect the disconnection and reconnect as long as the client works correctly so there's no problem with disconnecting. However, another software cannot handle the disconnections so I would need different config for the database it uses.